# Merging different column values in a single row in Oracle 9i

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

The initial table is looks like as follows

```
ACCOUNTNO  CABLE    INTERNET    PHONE

2527698    LARGE        
2527698    LARGE        
2527698              TIER 2 
2527698    LARGE        
2527698                         MONT-TEL-2016-BASIC-PHONE
2527698    LARGE
```

We need to fetch the records as (in Oracle 9i)

```
ACCOUNTNO   CABLE   INTERNET    PHONE           
2527698     LARGE   TIER 2  MONT-TEL-2016-BASIC-PHONE
```

Comment: What happens if one of the CABLE is `SMALL`? What should you get then?

Comment: SELECT ACCOUTNO,CABLE,INTERNET,PHONE
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY ACCOUTNO,CABLE,INTERNET,PHONE

Comment: @sagi>>Sorry, this doesn't work.

It shows

ACCOUNTNO CABLE INTERNET PHONE

2527698     LARGE  
2527698                  TIER 2 
2527698                                  MONT-TEL-2016-BASIC-PHONE

Comment: @Ben

Cable column value will remain same for all the rows, so if it is small then it should be small for all the cable values

Comment: It will be

SELECT ACCOUNTNO,max(CABLE),max(INTERNET),max(PHONE) FROM RPT_NEWORDERS_CONNECTS 
GROUP BY ACCOUNTNO 

thanks for your help